# Como controlar el acceso a ciertas rutas con Guard de Angular? dependiendo si esta logeado o no

Tags: php, javascript, html, angular, local-storage

Tengo un login en Angular que desde php me dice si existe o no, la cuestión que quiero restringir el acceso a ciertas rutas dependiendo si esta logeado o no, para esto pense hacerlo con un Guard y guardar alguna variable de sesion en localStorage. Necesito ideas, una ayuda. Gracias

esto es en el Guard

```
  canActivate(){
    if( condicionParaValidarPaso ){
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      console.log('asda');
      return false
    }else{
      return true
    }
```

esto es la funcion de loguearse

```
  loguearse(post){
    this.post = post;

    console.log(this.post);
    this.http.post<any>("http://localhost/abm/register.php", {
      action: "login",
      data: this.post
    }).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.LoginServiceService.verVariable(data.tipoDeUsuario);
          // localStorage.setItem('userEmail', this.post.emailLogin);
          if( data.resultado == true ){
            setTimeout( ()=>{
                this._Router.navigate(["/gestion-socios"]);
            }, 200 )
          } else{
            alert('Email o contraseña incorrecto');
          }
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err);
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            console.log("Client-side error occured.");
          } else {
            console.log("Server-side error occured.");
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Guarda el resultado del inicio de sesion en una variable boolean y usa esa variable como condicion para permitir el paso.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un AuthGuard extendentiendo la interfaz CanActivate de ésta manera.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../services';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            return true;
        }
l
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Y posteriormente utilizarlo en tú modulo routing

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},

{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

];

Espero te sirva.